# Авто приведение базового класса к классу потомка

Tags: c++, ооп

Есть 1 базовый класс и 2 класса наследника.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <map>
using namespace std;
class NotBase1;
class NotBase2;
class Base;

class Base{    
public:

    int a=0;
    template<typename T>
    T* get_type();

};


class NotBase1:public Base{
    public:
    NotBase1* get_type(){
        return this;
    }

    int z =90;

};

class NotBase2:public Base{
public :

    NotBase2* get_type(){
        return this;
    }
    int p = 100;

};


int main() {
    std::vector<Base*> stru;
    NotBase1* b1 = new NotBase1;
    NotBase2* b2 = new NotBase2;
stru.push_back(b1);
stru.push_back(b2);

stru[0]->get_type<NotBase1>()->z;

    return 0;
}
```

Каким образом и можно ли, при обращении к элементу вектора, работать с его элементами как с дочерними объектами класса? Не используя шаблоны и не указывая явно какого типа объект как тут stru[0]->get_type()->z;

Comment: Для задач, где это может понадобится есть полиморфизм. А для подобных извращений посмотрите на std::tuple.

Comment: Я понял, так делать не нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нельзя делать то что Вы хотите, что должно произойти в Вашем примере, если в `stru[0]` будет находится не `NotBase1`, а `NotBase2` ?

Вот примерная попытка адаптировать Вашу задачу:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Base
{
public:
    int a = 0;

    virtual int getValue() const = 0;
};


class NotBase1 : public Base
{
    public:

    int getValue() const override
    {
        return z;
    }

    int z = 90;

};

class NotBase2 : public Base
{
public:
    int getValue() const override
    {
        return p;
    }

    int p = 100;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::vector<Base*> stru;
    stru.push_back(new NotBase1);
    stru.push_back(new NotBase2);


    for(Base *item : stru)
    {
        std::cout << item->getValue() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

```
90
100
```

Для того чтоб все-таки достучатся к переменных наследуемых типов, то можно воспользоваться `dynamic_cast`. Но это пример плохого кода.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::vector<Base*> stru;
    stru.push_back(new NotBase1);
    stru.push_back(new NotBase2);

    for(Base *item : stru)
    {
        NotBase1 *derived1 = dynamic_cast<NotBase1*>(item);
        if(derived1)
        {
            std::cout << derived1->z << std::endl;
        }

        NotBase2 *derived2 = dynamic_cast<NotBase2*>(item);
        if(derived2)
        {
            std::cout << derived2->p << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Если передать шаблону неверный тип, приложение вылетит в чужую память. Соответственно будет segmentation fault. Да, то что Вы показали, это интерфейс. В дочерних структурах, хранятся совершенно разные данные, я не могу создать для них общий интерфейс. Я понимаю, что проблема в архитектуре. Но не нахожу лучшего решения.

Comment: В языке с++ нет "динамического угадывания типа". Значит либо делается общий интерфейс, либо dynamic_cast, либо переменная, в которой хранится "тип" (такой ручной каст), либо более модные std::variant/visit

Answer (score 1):

Либо разрабатывайте свой дизайн в стиле классического ООП с общим полиморфным интерфейсом в терминах концепций боле высокого уровня, не зависящих от конкретного типа (например так, как это сделано в ответе @Александр).

Либо разрабатывайте свой дизайн вокруг новых средств языка, вроде `std::variant` и `std::visit`

```
#include <vector>
#include <variant>
#include <iostream>

class NotBase1
{
public:
  int z = 90;
};

class NotBase2 
{
public:
  int p = 100;
};

struct visitor
{
  void operator()(const NotBase1 *p) { std::cout << p->z << std::endl; }
  void operator()(const NotBase2 *p) { std::cout << p->p << std::endl; }
};

int main() 
{
  std::vector<std::variant<NotBase1 *, NotBase2 *>> stru;
  stru.push_back(new NotBase1);
  stru.push_back(new NotBase2);

  std::visit(visitor(), stru[0]);
  std::visit(visitor(), stru[1]);
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/98136d280e8a65c3

Comment: Если необходимость писать полный перечень наследников в шаблонных параметрах `variant`а режет глаз, то можно написать свой кастомный variant, и как шаблонные параметры передавать ему только базовый класс и нужный `visitor`. Как-то экспериментировал с этим, вот что получилось: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/197579/deep-copyable-unique-ptr-wrapper-with-stdvisit-like-feature